# Filter table by multiple options

Tags: php, laravel, filter

I have some `<select>` with `<option>` with foreach. I have

```
 <select class="form-control" name="agent" id="agent">
                        <option value="toti">All</option>
                        @foreach($values as $value)
                        <option value="{{$value->id_value}}">{{$value->val_name}}</option>
                        @endforeach 
                    </select>
```

And

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
    <select class="form-control" name="timp" id="timp">
        <option value="tot">All days</option>
        <option value="today">Today</option>
        <option value="7d">Last 7 days</option>
        <option value="30d">Last 30 days</option>
     </select>
  </div>




  <div class="col-md-2">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Data" class="form-control" value="Data" name="data" id="data" >
     <div class="input-group date">
     <input type="text" name="data_filt"  id="data_filt" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
  </div>

$id_user = Auth::user()->id();
$cars = Cars::whereFk_user($id_user)
  ->join('cars_my_cars', 'cars_my_cars.id_cars', '=', 'cars.fk_data_cars')
  ->join('cars_bill', 'partners_cars.id_date_partener', '=', 'cars.fk_date_partener')
  ->OrderBy('id_car', 'desc')->paginate(15);

  $agenti = Agent::whereFk_user($id_user)->get();
  $parteneri = Partener::whereFk_user($id_user)->OrderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
```

I want with this to filter a table in Laravel. By agent, by days and date. I will have this 3 and one button to submit the option...but how can I do this?

Comment: use ajax, whenever `select` will changed send a request and get response from ajax. this is the best way (speed)

Comment: So where is the code that get the data from the database?

Comment: I don't want to use ajax because I have a lot of data and I need pagination

Comment: so what??? you need pagination but what is the problem to use ajax??can plz explain'

Comment: If i will use ajax how can I get just 10 'posts'? on a page..and to get the next 10 on other page. I can't do this because if I will have 1000000 posts..the page will work...so hard

Comment: if you want only 10 post then use limit 0,10 and for next use pre and post hidden value in limit like limit prevalue,postvalue it would be easy to you to get new page via ajax